# Confidence interval for linear regression

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I need to create confidence interval for linear regression using R-lang. I followed a few tutorials, yet my result is quite different. As far as I am concerned, I should get two lines, one above and one below the main line, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5cQA.jpg).

Unfortunately what I got is a few stacked lines, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9KrO.png).

Could anyone help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Here's sample of my code:

```
speed <- c(61,225,110,51,114,68,24,24,133,83,83,92,93,37,111,172,142,105,143,77,154,108,98,164,124,97,90,87,137,71,73,74,62,88,100,101,126,113,49)
length <- c(58,149,90,55,91,69,31,35,109,77,78,82,86,44,89,121,106,98,116,65,111,88,86,122,104,85,72,80,105,74,71,66,73,72,72,90,91,98,59);
cars <- data.frame(speed, length)

modelReg <- lm(length ~ speed, data = cars)

x <- cars$speed
conf_interval <- predict(modelReg, newdata =  data.frame(seq(from=min(x),to=max(x),by = 1)),interval = 'confidence')
lines(x,conf_interval[,2],lty=2)
lines(x,conf_interval[,3],lty=2)
```

Comment: `lines(seq(from=min(x),to=max(x),by = 1), etc)`. Or assign `new_x <- seq(from=min(x),to=max(x),by = 1)` and then `lines(new_x, etc)`.

Comment: `newdata` should have a column named speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first four lines of your code above, use Gosink's `plot.add.ci` function:

```
# John Gosink's Intervals Plotter (from http://gosink.org/?page_id=120)
plot.add.ci <- function(x, y, interval='prediction', level=0.9, 
regressionColor='red', ...) {
    xOrder  <- order(x)
    x       <- x[xOrder]  
    y       <- y[xOrder]
    fit     <- lm(y ~ x, data=data.frame(x=x, y=y))
    newX    <- data.frame(x=jitter(x))
    fitPred <- predict.lm(fit,newdata=newX,interval=interval,level=level, ...)
    abline(lm(y ~ x), col=regressionColor)
    lines(newX$x, fitPred[,2], lty=2, ...)
    lines(newX$x, fitPred[,3], lty=2, ...)
}

plot(cars$speed,cars$length)
abline(modelReg,col="red")
plot.add.ci(speed, length, level=0.95, interval="confidence", lwd=3)
```

Which gives this plot (change `level` if you want a different confidence level, or drop `interval=` for a prediction interval):

[image]